# akh text not updating from settimer

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to change text from set timer. It is not working. Here is the pseudo code what I am trying to do

```
Gui, New, , Update Text Demo
gui, add, text, x20 y20 w100 h16 vtimertext, --------
Gui, show, w600 h300

TimePassed = 0

SetTimer, UpdateTime, 3000
gosub UpdateTime

Return

; The following label receives control when the user closes the GUI window.
GuiClose:
{
  ExitApp
}

Return

UpdateTime:
{
  TimePassed := (TimePassed + 1)
  TrayTip, Debug, %TimePassed%
  GuiControl,,timertext,%TimePassed%
}

Return
```

As you can see, timer text is not changing when it is called from the settimer event.

Could someone please point out if I am doing something wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the [answer](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=28521) from AHK Forun submitted by 4GForce [and SO from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46732121/119540) Jim U. I am putting the answer below for quick reference.

> Well, GuiControl,, TimerText wasn't found because it wasn't a global
>   variable. To avoid global you need to specify the gui name. ( it was
>   also missing the Text command ) Hope you don't mind, I changed a few
>   things like removing your TimePassed variable
>
> ```
> Gui MyGui:New, , % "Update Text Demo"
> Gui MyGui:Add, Text, x20 y20 w100 h16 vTimerText, % "0"
> Gui MyGui:Show, w600 h300
> …
> GuiControl, MyGui: ,timertext,%TimePassed%
> ```

Basically, what's happening is that the timer thread defaults to its own separate GUI, not the one from the main thread, so you need to name the main GUI and use that name while building it, and when updating it in the timer subroutine.

Comment: Are you sure it works? The number in the bubble changes, but the text in the GUI still does not. 

Comment: I fixed the answer (you missed the gui-name in the call to `GuiControl`) and added an explanation.