# function containing GuiControl doesn't work with hotkey

Tags: autohotkey

```
test() {
    GuiControl, , abc, 123456789
}

GUI New
GUI Add, ListBox, xm y+m w100 h100 vabc
GUI Add, Button, xm y+m w60 h30 grun, Add
GUI Show, Autosize
Return

run:
    test()
    return

GuiClose:
    ExitApp

!1::
    test()
    MsgBox 1
    return
```

I wanna call test() when I press the key Alt + 1, But my code above doesn't work. Only the message '1' is output.

Obviously I seem to be misunderstanding something.. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This displays a GUI window containing a list control and appends a row with "123456789" to it when <kbd>ALT-1</kbd> is pressed**

```
test() {
  GuiControl Alpha:, abc, 123456789
}

GUI Alpha: New
GUI Add, ListBox, xm y+m w100 h100 vabc
GUI Add, Button, xm y+m w60 h30 grun, Add
GUI Show, Autosize
Return

run:
    test()
    return

GuiClose:
    ExitApp

!1::
    test()
    return
```

---

GUI commands within hotkeys will refer to different gui threads by default. You can use a [GUI Name](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#New) (`Alpha:` in the above example) to specify an existing GUI window.

Comment: `GUI commands within hotkeys will refer to different gui threads by default.` Eureka! Thanks! 